# OpenGL landmark inversion

Tags: opengl

I making a snake in 3 different graphic's library (`SDL`,`Ncurses`, `OpenGL`) but I've some problem with `OpenGL`.

The `OpenGL` landmark is on the left bottom while other are on left top.

Does somebody know ho to inverse my `OpenGL` landmark ?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple thing one can do is to apply a scaling along the y-axis by -1 (a mirroring) after the projection.

Note, that this might have some side-effects, e.g., the winding order of primitives will be flipped after the mirroring.

Comment: Thanks BDL for your answer, could you explain me what do you mean by "the winding order of primitives will be flipped" ?

Comment: That is important for backface culling. When you send your triangles in counter-clockwise order and invert the window coordinates, then this triangles will be clockwise.

Comment: I've postiion x and y to draw my characters but If I draw it in x position and y * -1 position my character are out of my landmark...